# Cyclic groups isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If a group has order $p$, where $p$ is a prime number, why is the group cyclic? Furthermore, why is it isomorphic to integers modulo $p$?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the subgroup $\langle g \rangle = \{g^k \ | \ k \in \mathbb{N} \}$ for any non-identity $g \in G$.  What do we know about the order of this subgroup?  What does this tell us about $g$?

Next, consider how $g$ is similar to $1 \in (\mathbb{Z}_p, +)$.  This should give an idea for the isomorphism $G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The order of an element divides the order of the group. As p is prime, all elements in the group either have order 1 or order p.